# Postgresql Backup script using pg_dump is throwing error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to take postgresql backup using the following shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "MyPassword" | sudo -S sudo su - postgres
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
cd /usr/pgsql-11/bin
pg_dump -U postgres -d db_prod > /home/db_backup_$today.sql
exit
```

The /home/db_backup has been modified with owner `postgres`. (`sudo chown postgres:postgres /home/db_backup`)

But I am getting the below error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "db_prod" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication 
failed for user "postgres"
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo su -` launches a new shell.  The rest of your script will not run until that shell exits, at which point you are back to being yourself (that is, you are no longer postgres)

This is an abomination anyway.  If you want your daily user account to be able to log into postgresql as the superuser, just configure postgresql to let you do that, rather than hard coding your password into shell scripts.

Comment: [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) file can be used if using password in schell script is in appropriate.

Comment: @SahapAsci Sure.  You can also set up peer auth to use pg_ident to map the local user to multiple allowed PostgreSQL users.